# File transfer through jump host

Tags: ssh, alias, scp

I need to move files to destination server(s) to which we have to pass-through 2 jump servers. Currently this is how my alias are setup

```
alias tst = 'ssh -A -t xjmp01 ssh -A -t xjmp02 ssh -A -t qat1'  
alias qat = 'ssh -A -t xjmp01 ssh -A -t xjmp02 ssh -A -t qat2'
```

if I do 'tst' in Putty I get connected to qat1

**Question:** is there any way I can use this setup to move files as well - if yes, how ?

I have tried using the information given here: [scp files via intermediate host](https://superuser.com/questions/276533/scp-files-via-intermediate-host)

but those don't work with alias setup that I have.

Comment: The `scp` won't work because you've not set up your `ssh` configuration in the way suggested by your referenced post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. set up proper configuration (in `~/.ssh/config`) to your jump boxes, instead of these ad-hoc aliases:

   ```
   Host xjmp01
     # other required configuration
   Host xjmp02
     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p xjmp01
   Host qat1
     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p xjmp02
   Host qat2
     ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p xjmp02
   ```
2. Now you should be able to connect to your hosts simply using

   ```
   ssh -A qat1
   ssh -A qat2
   ```
3. The same way you should be able to transfer files:

   ```
   scp upload_file qat1:
   scp qat1:download_file .
   ```